# Angularjs timeout

Tags: angularjs, timeout

why is this time out not working? I have injected $timeout in controller. Even moving timeout into http response is the same. Using angularjs 1.6.6 with Laravel 5.2. $scope.showInfo is true, but not false after 3000 ms.

```
$scope.submitAttendance = function(attData) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/save/attendance',
        headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
        data: attData
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        var response = response.data;
        if (response == 1) {
            $scope.msg = 'Attendance details saved to system';
            $scope.attData = {};
            $scope.attData.timeIn = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '08:00');
            $scope.attData.timeOut = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '16:00');

        } else {
            $scope.msg = 'Failed to save Attendance info';

        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        $scope.msg = 'There is a problem saving data at this time. Please contact Administrator';
    });

    $scope.showInfo = true;
    $timeout(function(){ $scope.showinfo = false; }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: whether your `$scope.showInfo` variable inside `$timeout` is not updating

Comment: yes, it is not becoming false.

Comment: change `$scope.showinfo` to `$scope.showInfo` inside $timeout

Comment: OMG, spent the whole night looking for answer. That was the problem. Thank you.